# How to run a laravel git clone in local

Tags: php, git, laravel-5, composer-php, git-clone

I have downloaded our Laravel project from `bitbucket` using

```
git clone https://SachithNalaka@bitbucket.org/team/project.git
```

Then I tried `composer install`

```
php artisan clear-compiled PHP Warning:  require(/home/sachith/xxxx/xxx_y/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sachith/xxxx/xxx_y/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17 
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/sachith/xxxx/xxx_y/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
/home/sachith/xxxx/xxx_y/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17 
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-install-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

I am confused how to run this, What did I miss here? How to run this properly?

Answer (score 2):

See laravel [issue 5066](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5066) and [PR 3687](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/3687)

> Can't rely on being able to run php artisan, before updating. See composer/composer#5066
>
> > Before, running install without a lock file did an install that was almost an update, but still ran the `pre/post-install-cmd` scripts.
> >     Now we normalized it to actually run an update and fire `pre/post-update-cmd`, because that's what it is doing.
> >     If you have a lock file though it will run install as before.
>
> When installing without lockfile, Composer now behaves as upgrade.
>   It also executes the pre-upgrade-cmd instead of pre-install-cmd. Behaviour with `composer.lock` available is not changed.

(that recent change [can affect some existing projects](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5079#issuecomment-197940603))

So maybe your `composer.lock` is missing from your repo?
With the latest composer version, doing a fresh install will fail because the vendor files are not yet present.

Comment: `composer.lock` file is in my repo, I read those issues, but don't know how to solve my problem.

Comment: @Sachith and what happen if you try after deleting your vendor folder?

Comment: In my clone, I do not have a vendor folder